# ASUS laptop doesn't boot after disassembly

Tags: motherboard, power, asus-laptop

One day I mentioned that cooler doesn't work so I dismantled my laptop to check that nothing prevents him from spinning and connector is OK. I took off the case, DVDROM, HDD, RAM. After that I cleaned the cooler, inserted RAM back, plugged in and turned on the laptop. BIOS appeared, but cooler still didn't work. I checked BIOS for cooler options, but found nothing. "OK, lets check the connector" I thought. I unscrewed another 4 bolts and flipped over the motherboard. Connector was on place. I placed the motherboard back and screwed it with these 4 bolts. BUT NOW when I plug in my laptop (I DOESN'T push power button!), it turns on automatically (cooler still doesn't work), the sreen is black and only 3 LED status indicators are on (Power Indicator, Capital Lock Indicator and Power Button). When the laptop is in this state and I push the Power button, it goes into a loop: turns off, then turns on for 3 seconds (state with 3 indicators) and then turns off again. What can it be? Thank you!

```
Notebook model: Asus K42F
CPU: Intel core i3 350m
RAM: 2GB
```

Comment: I would double check everything is connected correctly and nothing has come loose since you replaced the motherboard.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I checked twice and I am sure everything is OK. Except that my laptop doesn't work :(